# Why do geotargeted posts not appear in API even with accesstoken?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This has been asked before but I haven't seen a definitive answer. Hopefully someone has an answer. Basically, it seems impossible to pull any post that is geo-tageted via the API becasue it has privacy settings, that is, a country set to who can see it.

I am using `https://graph.facebook.com/".$pagetoprocess."/posts?&access_token=".$att` and this will pull the posts but not any posts that are geotargeted to the UK for example.

If I create an accesstoken from a user who is an admin of the page then I see all posts including geotargeted posts.

Why would this be? how can I see all posts for any page whether I am an admin or not or whether it is geo-targeted?

I would have thought that if you creaded an app in the UK and therefore had an app and secret id code from which you then generated a user access token, why would you not be able to see a post from a page geo-targeting the UK? Seems strange.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Jonathan

Answer (score 0):

I would think that all posts would appear, or at least that is what it says on the api. You could try using feed instead of posts, since posts is a derivative. You might also try using:

&include_hidden=TRUE

But I'm not sure that will help.

If you have the page url, I'd be willing to see if I can play around with it in the graph explorer.